# My total is 0 when I put quantity and price typescript html

Tags: html, angular, typescript, calculator

In angular 5 I am creating an application where user can select quantity and price of products and once they are done the product price with the quantity would be shown in the total price. This is my code, that display only Total 0

My html code:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
      <input formControlName="Quantity" id="Quantity " type="number" class="validate">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input formControlName="Unit_price" id="Unit_price" type="number" class="validate">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input formControlName="Subtotal" id="Subtotal" type="number" class="validate">
      <label for="Subtotal">Total {{Price}}</label>
    </div>
```

Ts code:

```
  Price: number = 0;
  products: Products[];

      countPrice() {
        this.Price = 0;
        for (let p of this.products) {
          this.Price += p.Unit_price * p.Quantity
        }
         }
```

Can you suggest me, what is the problem, and how to solve this?

Comment: where are you calling `countPrice` function ?

Comment: In html  {{Price}}

Comment: You would expect to see something like `(clicked)="countPrice()"` or similar causing the function to be run - where does this happen?

Comment: Its not working :(

Comment: Your code is just displaying things, without actually calling something (as already said, the countPrice() function is not called). Could you perhaps put your code on stackblitz or plunkr so we can have a look on it?

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling `countPrice` anywhere ( at least with the code you provided) .
So  `Total * {{Price}} = 0` since Price initial value is 0

Answer (score 0):

The value you are computing in the `countPrice` can directly be added to the template like this :

```
{{ form.values.Quantity * form.values.Unit_price }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your function **countPrice()**.
I have updated your code and called the **countPrice()** in html itself.

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <input formControlName="Quantity" id="Quantity " type="number" class="validate">
</div>
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <input formControlName="Unit_price" id="Unit_price" type="number" class="validate">
</div>
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <input formControlName="Subtotal" id="Subtotal" type="number" class="validate">
  <label for="Subtotal">Total {{countPrice()}}</label>
</div>
```

Now in your **countPrice()** function return **this.Price**
Refer the update function for this.

```
     Price: number = 0;
     products: Products[];

        countPrice() {
            this.Price = 0;
            for (let p of this.products) {
              this.Price += parseInt(p.Unit_price) * parseInt(p.Quantity)
            }
             return this.Price;
             }
```

Comment: the result is NaN

Comment: ohh I got it. You are taking quantity and price from input box. So in input box it will give as string. So you need to parse it. I am sharing the updated code.

Comment: check it now @Lonna

Comment: radix parameter missing

Comment: radix parameter is optional. Please refer this link to know more about it https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: Thnx. I write     this.Price += parseInt('p.Unit_price', 10) * parseInt('p.Quantity', 10)  and also is Nan

Comment: does you products array contains anything? can you please share the full component code in jsfiddle/plunkr